# TypeScript 3.7 recursive type references - Record vs index signature

Tags: typescript

I tried to use recursive type references introduced in TypeScript 3.7 in a very similar fashion to what was presented in [the official example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/recursive-type-references).

I made something slightly different than what was presented in the docs, but thought it should work in the same manner. It turns out it does not.

Using index signature in the recursion works as described in the documentation:

```
type Json = string | number | boolean | null | Json[] | { [key: string]: Json; };
```

However using `Record` type does not work - results in circular reference error

```
type Json = string | number | boolean | null | Json[] | Record<string, Json>;
```

And what is even more weird for me, manually expanding the `Record` type does work ok:

```
type Json = string | number | boolean | null | Json[] | { [key in string]: Json; };
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHcHsCcGsGcCwAoALgTwA4FNQCl5IA7ANQEsBDASSIBNsAPUAXlHlWjKIHNQAfUEQCuAWwBG2aP1BjIkADbYKRacPnzpBYuWp1GAbQC60gN6h9sbOgBcbDl26HbW0pRr0GAblABfTyhQQUFpIbHhBSFQIGFgAOniUDBx8QlcKACVsAGMYWhY7Th5VUQkpAVkFJRUBNQ0BFx1MnOhaI2km3IAedkLuABoU7UoOloA+f2RAsAAhISjUAAsycJCw6LgAfi3ErFwGygAFeGwhEJG81h6HYvFJaQrFZWL1TVSdI5Oz7Ny2gTMLKygLgFBxOQZpD6nSDnbx+IA)

Questions:
What is the difference between `{ [key: string]: X; }` and `Record<string, X>` that makes the difference with recursive types?
Isn't `Record<K, V>` equivalent to `{ [P in K]: V; }` i.e. `Record<string, X> === { [key in string]: X; }`? Why does it produce different results with recursive types?
What am I missing? Or is this a bug within TS?